# Why nested classes behave differently between Java and C#?

Tags: java, c#

I don't understand why the following code errors in Java:

```
public abstract class TestClass
{
    private final int data;

    protected TestClass(int data) { this.data = data; }

    public final class InnerClass extends TestClass
    {
    private InnerClass(int data) { super(data); }

    public static final TestClass CONSTANT = new InnerClass(5);
    }
}
```

The error is on the `public static final TestClass CONSTANT = new InnerClass(5);` part.
The errors are:

> I:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestingGround\src\testingground\TestClass.java:22:
>   error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static
>   context   public static final TestClass CONSTANT = new InnerClass(5);
>                                              ^ I:\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TestingGround\src\testingground\TestClass.java:22:
>   error: Illegal static declaration in inner class TestClass.InnerClass
>     public static final TestClass CONSTANT = new InnerClass(5);
>                                   ^   modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations 2 errors

If I try to achieve the same in C#, it works fine.

```
public abstract class TestClass
{
    private readonly int data;

    protected TestClass(int data) { this.data = data; }

    public sealed class InnerClass : TestClass
    {
        private InnerClass(int data) : base(data) { }

        public static readonly TestClass CONSTANT = new InnerClass(5);
    }
}
```

Why does Java not allow this?

Comment: I've updated title... Which unfortunately makes this question duplicate of many similar once http://www.bing.com/search?q=Why+nested+classes+behave+differently+between+Java+and+C%23%... but not many answered by Jon Skeet - so lets have another one :) Feel free to reword title to better reflect your problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov None of the 'duplicates' address this particular issue. One is asking why a C# nested class doesn't have access to its outer class' internals like a Java inner class does. One asks what the difference between a Java static class and a C# static class are, but it's a bit of a cognitive leap from the given answers to the problem in this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create an [*inner* class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) (as opposed to a nested static class) you need an instance of the enclosing class - you don't have one in this case. Note that there's no direct equivalent of inner classes in C# - a nested class in C# is more like a nested static class in Java, and the meaning of `static` in a class declaration in C# is entirely different to the meaning of `static` in a class declaration in Java.

**Option 1**

If you really *want* it to be an inner class, you can write:

```
public static final TestClass CONSTANT = new SomeConcreteTestClass().new InnerClass(5);
```

(Where `SomeConcreteTestClass` is a concrete class extending `TestClass`)

or, horribly:

```
public static final TestClass CONSTANT = ((TestClass) null).new InnerClass(5);
```

Note that you'd need to move the declaration out of `InnerClass` though, as inner classes can't declare static variables other than compile-time constant expressions:

> It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable (§4.12.4).

So you'd end up with:

```
public abstract class TestClass
{
    private final int data;

    protected TestClass(int data) { this.data = data; }

    public final class InnerClass extends TestClass
    {
        private InnerClass(int data) { super(data); }        
    }
    public static final TestClass CONSTANT = ((TestClass) null).new InnerClass(5);
}
```

**Option 2**

Just make `InnerClass` static:

```
public static final class InnerClass extends TestClass
```

The addition of `static` there is the only change required. That's now much more like a C# nested class (although generics behave differently, as always...) Ideally at that point you'd rename the class, as it's not an inner class...

Comment: I'll accept this in 4 minutes when I'm allowed. I was not aware it was possible to instantiate a static class in Java since I'm more used to C#. (Those weren't the actual names of my classes anyway, I simplified my classes for the sake of demonstration.) I know generics would apply differently, Java uses type erasure instead of whatever C#'s technique is, but thanks for the head up anyway. Most languages tend to treat generics differently for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Java language does not allow an inner class to declare a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable, see JLS 8.1.3

Comment: That's basically a rewording of the second error, and thus not helpful.

Comment: @Pharap: Well, it's an explanation of the *source* of the second error, with a reference to the JLS. It's not a complete explanation, but I wouldn't say it's "not helpful".

Comment: @JonSkeet Aside from the fact it wasn't helpful, just copy and pasting a section of the JLS without further elaboration does not make for a very good answer, no matter how simple or complicated the question.